Having troubles with creating sprites in tasm 8086
I want to create 5 submarine for the player and 5 to the computer (10 total) by using the sprites method. When i checked the DosBox for mistakes i saw that all of my sprites lines have the same error value out of range:(
assemblt tasm 8086

IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
p386
DATASEG
filename1 db 'picture1.bmp',0
filename2 db 'instr.bmp',0
filename3 db 'board2.bmp',0
filehandle1 dw ?
filehandle2 dw ?
filehandle3 dw ?
Header1 db 54 dup (0)
Header2 db 54 dup (0)
Header3 db 54 dup (0)
Palette1 db 256*4 dup (0)  
Palette2 db 256*4 dup (0)
Palette3 db 256*4 dup (0)
ScrLine1 db 320 dup (0)
ScrLine2 db 320 dup (0)
ScrLine3 db 320 dup (0)
ErrorMsg1 db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$'
ErrorMsg2 db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$'
ErrorMsg3 db 'Error', 13, 10 ,'$'
messageHit db 'Hit!:)', 13, 10, '$'
messageMiss db 'Miss:(..' , 13, 10, '$'
messageWin db 'You won!' , 13, 10, '$'
messageLost db 'You lost:(' , 13, 10, '$'

x dw 0
y dw 0
color db 4

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;sprites here


submarine1               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011010000000000000000000
                         db 0000000000000000011111111110000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111110000000000000
             db 0001110000000000111111111111000000000000
             db 0000111000001111111111111111111111111100
             db 0110011111111111111111111111111111111110
             db 0111111111111111111111111111111111111110
             db 0110011111111111111111111111111111111110
             db 0000111000011111111111111111111111111100
             db 0001110000000000000111111111111110000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000   ;size 40x14
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
submarine2           db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000010111000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000010111000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000010100000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000001111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000001111111111000000
                         db 0000000000000001000000001111111111100000
             db 0000000000000011000000111111111111110000
             db 0000000000000011001111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000111111111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000111111111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000001101111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000001100011111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000001000001111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000000000000111111111111110000
             db 0000000000000000000000001111111111100000
             db 0000000000000000000000000001111111000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  ; size 40x19
             
             
             
             
submarine3               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000011110000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000010000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000010000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000111000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000001111100000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000111111111111000000
             db 0000000000000000001101111111111111110000
             db 0000000000000000001111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000001111111111111111111111100
             db 0000000000000001111111111111111111111100
             db 0000000000000000001111111111111111111000
             db 0000000000000000001111111111111111110000
             db 0000000000000000001101111111111111100000
             db 0000000000000000000000111111111111000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ;size 40x16
             
             
             
submarine4               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111000000000000
             db 0000000000000001111111111111100000000000
             db 0000000000000011111111111111111000000000
             db 0000000000000111111111111111111100000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
                         db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
                         db 0000000000001111111111111111111110000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111110010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111111110
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111110000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
             db 0000000000001000001110011100000100000000
             db 0000000000000111110001100011111000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000111011100000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001000100010000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000111011100000000000000 ;size 40x23
             
             
             
             
             
             
                


submarine5               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000         
             db 0000000000000000001000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000110000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000110000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001111000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001111000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  ;size 40x18
             
;these sprites are for the player (left board)
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;these sprites will be for the computer (right board)


submarine6               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000010000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000010100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000110100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000111111111111111000000000000000
             db 0000000000111111111111111000000000000000
             db 0000000000111111111111111000000000011100
             db 0011111111111111111111111111100000111000
             db 0111111111111111111111111111111111000110
             db 0111111111111111111111111111111111111110
             db 0111111111111111111111111111111111000110
             db 0011111111111111111111111111110000111000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000011100
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ;size 40x14
             
             
             
             
             
             
submarine7               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000010111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000010111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000010100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000111110000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000111111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000001111111111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000011111111111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000111111111111111000001000000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111001100000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111001100000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111111110000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111111110000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111011000000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111000011000000000000000
             db 0000111111111111110000001000000000000000
             db 0000011111111111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000001111111000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  ;size 40x19
             
             
             
             
submarine8               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000             
             db 0000000000000111100000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000001110000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000011111000000000000000000000000
             db 0000001111111111110000000000000000000000
             db 0000111111111111111011000000000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111000000000000000000
             db 0011111111111111111111111000000000000000
             db 0011111111111111111111111000000000000000
             db 0001111111111111111111000000000000000000
             db 0000111111111111111111000000000000000000
             db 0000011111111110111011000000000000000000
             db 0000001111111100000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ;size 40x16
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
             
submarine9               db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111000000000000
             db 0000000000000001111111111111100000000000
             db 0000000000000011111111111111111000000000
             db 0000000000000111111111111111111100000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
                         db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
                         db 0000000000001111111111111111111110000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111110010
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111111110
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111111000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111110000000
             db 0000000000001111111111111111111100000000
             db 0000000000001000001110011100000100000000
             db 0000000000000111110001100011111000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000111011100000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001000100010000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000111011100000000000000 ;size 40x23




submarine10              db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000         
             db 0000000000000000001000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001000000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111111111110000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111110000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000011111100000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000110000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000110000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001111000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000001111000000000000000000
             db 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  ;size 40x18

`

I searched the internet for solutions and how other programers in tasm 8086 have created sprites but couldnt solve my problem
Thanks in advance:))

Your values are not binary and even if they were, they would not fit into a byte.


I searched the internet for solutions and how other programers in tasm 8086 have created sprites but couldnt solve my problem

Then maybe you forgot to search this here forum. This is an answer about displaying a 8086 sprite that I gave just recently.

When i checked the DosBox for mistakes i saw that all of my sprites lines have the same error value out of range

All of those sprite lines have the form db 0110011111111111111111111111111111111110. TASM does not recognize that as an allowed operand for the db directive. If your intention were to use the binary representation of a number then you would have had to suffix the digits with the B character. Sadly, at 40 binary digits it would not fit in a byte (8 bits), and not even in a word (16 bits) or in a dword (32 bits).
Several solutions exist but the solution that I propose is to use a string for this. Then all it takes is surrounding the 40 digits by string quotes:
db "0110011111111111111111111111111111111110"

It consumes more bytes than a purely numerical solution, but you keep a clear view over the picture within the sprite.
This is an example of showing the first sprite in the middle of the 320x200 screen. Please note that you are missing 2 lines for this sprite! Stating 40x14 but only showing 12 lines:
x            dw 140
y            dw 93
color        db 4
submarine1   db 14
             db "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
             db "0000000000000000011010000000000000000000"
             db "0000000000000000011111111110000000000000"
             db "0000000000000000011111111110000000000000"

  ...

  mov  ax, 0013h       ; AH=00h BIOS function number, AL=13h Mode number
  int  10h

  mov  si, offset submarine1
  call PrintSprite

  ...

; IN (si) OUT () MOD (ax,bx,cx,dx,si)
PrintSprite:
  push bp
  lodsb                ; Number of lines {14,16,18,19,23}
  mov  bl, al          ; Outer loop counter
  mov  bh, 0           ; Select display page (some BIOSes require this)
  mov  cx, x           ; Set initial X position
  mov  dx, y           ; Set initial Y position
OuterLoop:
  mov  bp, 40          ; Inner loop counter
InnerLoop:
  mov  al, 0           ; Background color (Black)
  cmp  byte ptr [si], '0'
  je   Plot
  mov  al, color       ; Foreground color
Plot:
  mov  ah, 0Ch         ; Set AH to 0Ch for plot pixel function
  int  10h             ; Plot the pixel
  inc  cx              ; Increment X
  inc  si              ; Move to next byte in sprite string
  dec  bp              ; Check inner loop counter
  jnz  InnerLoop       ; Repeat inner loop if less than 40 pixels
  sub  cx, 40
  inc  dx              ; Increment Y
  dec  bl              ; Check outer loop counter
  jnz  OuterLoop       ; Repeat outer loop if less than ? lines
  pop  bp
  ret

